# Is there a way to transfer many files at once to my SD card through an USB port?

Tags: usb, sd-card, file-transfer

I've been having some trouble transferring files to my SD card on my phone through my USB cable because they start getting corrupted after some point.

After some research, it seems like USB doesn't deal well with many files transferring at once. Since I have way too many files (about 7000) to transfer, it is unviable for me to copy them in small batches.

So I am looking for a way to transfer them all through my cable in one go without corrupting them.

Is there any way to do this? Maybe a program that transfers the files one by one automatically for me?

Comment: why through usb? copy folders with total commander

Comment: hmmm... how does total commander work?

I am trying through usb since it is the only appendage i have to connect my pc to my phone for file transferring purposes

Comment: You don't tell use what OS or tool you use on PC side. If you just copy files via USB you are using MTP protocol which is a very primitive and unreliable protocol. For large file transfers I would recommend to enable Android Debug bridge on the phone and use `adb` from Android SDK.

Comment: I've tried adb push to transfer my files, but it ended on lots of corrupted files even still... I thought that adb could be having the same problems as the simple windows copy paste, can that even be the case? There is a high possibility my SD card is simply corrupted, although after the point my files get corrupted if I try pasting a few files they work just fine.

Comment: I misunderstood. I thought you want transfer files to SD card on phone (to prevent getting corrupted). There was no mention about we're dealing with files on PC. you may try [winadb-sync](https://gitlab.com/aIecxs/winadb-sync)

Comment: I see. I'll try that, but I am thinking now my sd card really is corrupted. In any case, I think that could be helpful, so I'll try it out another time. Thanks!